# Execute root command in shell script and change to normal user after a process

Tags: shell

I am trying to create a shell script where it uses the root access to install all the dependencies and after completing it, it exits from the root command and continue executing the script as normal user.

This is the test code:

```
#!/bin/sh

output=$(whoami)

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]
then
    su -c "echo \"hi\""
    echo $output
    //continue doing some installtion 
    exit
fi

echo $output //this should show the normal username not the root name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

su -c 'echo $(whoami)'
echo $(whoami)
```

When you pass the command with **su** following with an option **-c** it runs as **root** user, so when you want to install any dependencies you can run the following command as shown in above example.

Comment: I have tried this method are there any other methods?